# Условия в .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url

появился такой вопрос можно ли делать условия в .htaccess в таком формате:

Если пользователь перешёл на сайт через google.com - то редирект срабатывает site.com/111

Если пользователь попал на сайт через любой другой сайт или напрямую - то редирект на site.com/222

Можно ли это реализовать ?

Answer (score 0):

Потенциально у вас должно быть что-то вида

```
RewriteCond    %{HTTP_REFERER}     ^https?://google\.com
RewriteRule    ^/?$   /111     [R]
RewriteRule    ^/?$   /222     [R]
```

Comment: Стало выбивать 500 ошибку Internal Server Error :(

Comment: @Merlin опечатка была во втором слове `RewriteRule`, убрали?

Comment: Ошибки 500 нету, но редиректы не срабатывают, пробовал даже вместо гугла разные ссайты вставлять - просто открывается главная страница сайта

Comment: ну тут правило о переходе с гугла на главную страницу сайта, а не на любую. Если надо любую то `^/?$` заменить на `.*` или `^(.*)`